# Unwanted comma in \textcite/\citet

Tags: biblatex

I've just upgraded to MikTeX 2.9, and find that `biblatex` under the `natbib=true` and `style=authoryear` options now interprets the `\citet{}` command to place a comma between authors' names and the bracketed year.

This was not the case under my previous MikTeX.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbib=true,style=authoryear,backend=bibtex]{biblatex} 

\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
From the outset, \citet{mar-84} gives the end away.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

where the contents of 'bib.bib' include

```
@BOOK{mar-84,
  author = {Gabriel Garcia Marquez},
  title = {Cien a\~{n}os de soledad},
  year = 1984,
  publisher = {Catedra}
}
```

I'd be grateful to hear of solutions or workarounds.

Comment: This is a known issue with `biblatex` 3.3, it is already addressed in the development version 3.4 (not on CTAN yet), see [issue #373 at the `biblatex` bug tracker](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/373)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a temporary bug in `biblatex` 3.3, it has already been addressed in `biblatex` 3.4, see [issue #373 at the `biblatex` bug tracker](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/373). Indeed, the old system has been replaced by something far fancier. Said system had a slight problem with certain styles that was only fixed in version 3.5, see [Unwanted comma between author and year using citet command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312539/35864).

`biblatex` 3.4 and 3.5 have been released now (indeed the current version is 3.7). Simply update `biblatex` and Biber to their recent versions.

---

If you want to fix the problem in `biblatex` 3.3, you need to redefine the `textcite` bibmacro. The exact code needed depends on the style, the rule of thumb is that you have to replace all occurrences of `\nonameyeardelim\bibopenparen` and `\nameyeardelim\bibopenparen` by `\addspace\bibopenparen` and `\addspace\bibopenparen`, respectively, in the `textcite` bibmacro.

For `authoryear` you need

```
\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{%
          \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
          \addspace\bibopenparen}%
        \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
          {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
          {}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit{%
       \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
       \addspace\bibopenparen}%
     \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
       {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
       {}%
     \usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
```

Comment: If you only use `\citet` or don't like the comma between the name and year anyway, you could also use `\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}`