# Different comma placement in textcite and parencite,

Tags: citing

I have a problem with 'mit-quotes'.
There is always a comma between 'et al.' and the year in textcite, but I only want this comma in parencite,

What I want:

- when I use `\textcite` I want this "Author et al. (2000)"
- when I use `\parencite` I want this "(Author et al., 2000)"

I had no problem with this before updating `biber` and `biblatex`. Just a month ago with `biblatex` 3.0 this worked fine. But as I was not able to do a downgrade for `biblatex`, I wanted to ask for a solution with the newest versions of `biber` and `biblatex`.

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, toc=graduated, fleqn,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc, captions=bottombeside]{scrbook}
\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{\vspace*{0\baselineskip}}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} 

\usepackage[backend=biber, natbib=true,citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=authoryear, uniquename=false,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{bibencoding=latin1,bibwarn=true,sortlocale=DE,isbn=false,url=false,doi=false,eprint=false,clearlang=true,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=2,uniquelist=false,sorting=nyt}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={\textit{et~al.}}}
\AtBeginBibliography{% 
    \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}}
\renewcommand\nameyeardelim{, }

 \bibliography{lit.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{lit.bib}
@book{Peng.2000,
    author = {Peng and Hopper},
    year = {2000},
    title = {Title},
    publisher = {Publisher},
}

    @book{Hans.2014,
        author = {Hans and Gretel and Grimm},
        year = {2014},
        title = {Title},
        publisher = {Publisher},
    }
\end{filecontents}



\begin{document}

 \cite{Peng.2000}\\
 \textcite{Peng.2000}\\
    \parencite{Peng.2000}\\

\cite{Hans.2014}\\
\textcite{Hans.2014}\\
\parencite{Hans.2014}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: This will be solved with the next biblatex version (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/373). If you can't wait you could download the development version (along with the development version of biber).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug in the `biblatex` package that has been resolved in the current version. An update will solve the problem.

Comment: Note that instead of `\renewcommand\nameyeardelim{, }`, the more `biblatex`-y way is `\renewcommand*\nameyeardelim{\addcomma\space}`. You might also want to have something like `DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={\textit{et~al\addot}}}` to make sure the `.` isn't seen as a full stop. The command `\mkbibnamelast` is now called `\mkbibnamefamily`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/305783/35864