# Unwanted comma between author and year using citet command

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I've been using the biblatex package for a while, and since updating my TeX installation (post-el capitan upgrade) I have been experiencing the following.

If the following is typed:

```
Such and such has been said \citep[111]{citekey}.
```

The following text is displayed:

```
Such and such has been said (Author, 2016, p. 111).
```

And if the following is typed:

```
\citet[111]{citekey} has said such and such.
```

The following text is displayed:

```
Author, (2016, p. 111) has said such and such.
```

The citep command is working as I want it to, but I do not want a comma placed after the author's name when using the citet command. I would like it to display as follows:

```
Author (2016, p. 111) has said such and such.
```

If I use the \citeyearpar command, it is fine, but I would rather not have to type the author's name in manually.

Here is the command placed in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear-icomp, url=true, isbn=false, natbib=true, sortcites=true, block=space, pagetracker=false, loccittracker=constrict]{biblatex}
```

Here is an example of an entry in my bib file (made using BibDesk):

```
@article{poldrack2006,
Author = {Poldrack, Russell},
Journal = {Trends in Cognitive Sciences},
Number = {2},
Pages = {59--63},
Title = {{Can cognitive processes be inferred from neuroimaging data?}},
Volume = {10},
Year = {2006}}
```

I have also tried changing the entry to the following:

```
@article{poldrack2006,
Author = {Russell Poldrack},
Journal = {Trends in Cognitive Sciences},
Number = {2},
Pages = {59--63},
Title = {{Can cognitive processes be inferred from neuroimaging data?}},
Volume = {10},
Year = {2006}}
```

The bibliography entry appears as follows, and is fine:

Poldrack, Russell (2006). “Can cognitive processes be inferred from neuroimaging data?” In: *Trends in Cognitive Sciences* 10.2, pp. 59–63.

Thank you for any help that can be offered.

Answer (score 12):

> The issue has been resolved in version `3.5` of `biblatex`. (At least for all standard styles. Custom styles may need further tweaks, see below.)
>
> If you are still having this problem, please update your TeX distribution. If the issue occurs with a custom style and does not go away after updating, notify the style author.
>
> If you are using an online service, note that Overleaf v1 still uses the now quite outdated version 3.4 (2016/05/14) of `biblatex`. Overleaf v2 has `biblatex 2016/12/05 v3.7`, where the issue should be resolved.

`biblatex`'s [new context-sensitive delimiter system](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/373) is a bit confused by the two-pass structure of the `\textcite` macro (which internally calls the command `\cbx@textcite` to do all the work), you will need the line

```
\DeclareDelimFormat[cbx@textcite]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
```

to help it along.

As PLK notes in the comments this issue ([#432](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/432)) has been resolved for all the standard styles in version 3.5 of `biblatex`. If you use a custom style that uses the two-pass `\textcite` but has not been updated yet, you might need

```
\DeclareDelimcontextAlias{cbx@textcite}{textcite}
```

instead.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp, natbib=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareDelimFormat[cbx@textcite]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

\begin{document}
\citet{sigfridsson}

\citereset\textcite{sigfridsson}

\citereset\citep{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is fixed in 3.5 DEV. A new delimiter aliasing mechanism is used which has default settings to cover this case.

Comment: Thank you for both of the responses. I've decided to download biblatex 3.5, and the issue has been resolved.

Comment: Adding `\DeclareDelimcontextAlias...` as in the MWE works as well!

Comment: How to upgrade biblatex 3.5 under Ubuntu? I have the same problem with the unwanted coma and the solution provided above does not work, so I would like to upgrade biblatex.

Comment: @ben If you are using the repository version of TeX live (installed via `apt get` or the like) you have to wait for the Ubuntu developers to push updates (that is unlikely to happen soon). You can install [vanilla TeX live](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864) instead where you can use `tlmgr` for updates. (I have gotten into trouble for suggesting this - one of the people involved with Ubuntu and TeX live development is not keen on this solution, but it is certainly what I would do). If you can't update and you are on 3.4 use the code from my answer.

Comment: @moewe. Thank you for your answer, but the code from your answer does not work for me - maybe I am not on 3.4. I tried to install vanilla TeX live but it's very hard for me, I followed the instructions but did not understand. Is there a link to a more user friendly way of installing vanilla TeX live?

Comment: @ben It should work for 3.4, so indeed it could be that you are not on 3.4, but only on 3.3, where the solution is different again. The post I linked to gives the best and most user-friendly installation help that I know of. But then I am on Windows and use MikTeX, so I'm not an expert on TeX live issues.

Comment: @ben The code for 3.3 can be found in http://golatex.de/neue-biber-version-ploetzlich-komma-bei-zitierung-t17005.html (sorry, it's German, the code you need is in the fourth post down '17.03.2016, 13:00')