# Biblatex adds comma before parentheses

Tags: biblatex, biber

This is recent behavior, but I couldn't figure out since exactly when this is happening:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{foo.bib}
@misc{Fallick2004a,
author = {Fallick, Bruce and Fleischman, Charles A.},
title = {{Employer-to-Employer Flows in the U.S. Labor Market: The Complete Picture of Gross Worker Flows}},
url = {http://www.federalreserve.gov/econresdata/researchdata/feds200434.html},
year = {2004}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-comp,
    natbib=true
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{foo}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\citet{Fallick2004a}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

```
Fallick and Fleischman, (2004)
```

This happens for all sorts of references, but only `textcite` and `citet`, not `citep`. I tried re-installing

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

to no avail.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on a TeXlive 2016 installation. I get the reference without comma.

Comment: Consider removing the `texlive` packages from Debian/Ubuntu and [installing the latest TeXLive distribution](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) separately.

Comment: This was an issue in an older version of `biblatex`. It is fixed now, you should consider updating. (If you use the repository version of TeX live, which often is outdated, you could consider switching to a "vanilla" TeX live: [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864)). See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/373, I can't reproduce your output with `biblatex` 3.5

Comment: @AlanMunn I used the document code as given and ran pdflatex, biber, pdflatex, pdflatex (without options to the commands, but with `natbib=true` for the `biblatex` package). I installed TL2016 only today, so maybe it is a recent change? I have `biblatex 2016/09/17 v3.6` installed.

Comment: @moewe Clearly not up-to-date. :)  I'm updating now on this machine; I see there's a `biblatex` update, so I assume it will be fixed. (Yes, fixed now.)

Comment: It could also be the problem from [Unwanted comma between author and year using citet command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312539/35864), which is resolved in 3.5 only. (The other issue should have been resolved in 3.4, I believe.)

Comment: @AlanMunn Ah, brilliant.