# Reformat the \citet command

Tags: biblatex

I am currently writing my thesis and wanted to change a bit the citation style so that it looked and read better.
I am using the famous `classicthesis` and added the following to the config:

```
\usepackage[maxcitenames=2,citestyle=authoryear,natbib=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

So that I could use `\citet` and `\citep` in my `.tex` files.

This is what I get with `\citet`

> Bowman, (2005)

This is what I get with `\citep`

> (Bowman, 2005)

However I would very much like to get read of the additional coma in the `\citet` in order to only get

> Bowman (2005)

To do that I tried to define a command on my own

```
\newcommand{\citetL}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}~(\citeyear{#1})}
```

which gives me the desired output except for the fact that the hyperlink that would usually get me to the reference (when I click on the year) is now gone.

Do you have a better solution or at least a way to add the hyperlink to get to the reference when I click on the year?

Related (somehow) to that issue is the fact that my final list of references is still numerical

> [1] Bowman.... 2005
>
> [2] Bowman.... 2006

Instead of

> Bowman 2005:
>
> Bowman 2006:

Would you know where this may come from?

---

After replacing my old version of TexLive with the 2017 version I get the following error:

> Package etoolbox Error: Toggle 'blx@bibtex8' already defined.

A MWE can be found below:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} % fix some latex issues see: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/fixltx2e.pdf
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig} %For subfigure
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{eurosym}  
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{soul}



%********************************************************************
% Note: Make all your adjustments in here
%*******************************************************
%\input{classicthesis-config}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\PassOptionsToPackage{%
    %backend=biber, %instead of bibtex
    backend=bibtex8,bibencoding=ascii,%
    language=auto,%
    style=numeric-comp,%
    %style=authoryear-comp, % Author 1999, 2010
    %bibstyle=authoryear,dashed=false, % dashed: substitute rep. author with ---
    sorting=nyt, % name, year, title
    maxbibnames=10, % default: 3, et al.
    %backref=true,%
    natbib=true % natbib compatibility mode (\citep and \citet still work)
}{biblatex}
    \usepackage[maxcitenames=2,citestyle=authoryear,natbib=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}


%********************************************************************
% Bibliographies
%*******************************************************
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
Text \cite{Besancon:2016:UCMTT}

%********************************************************************
% Other Stuff in the Back
%*******************************************************

\printbibliography


% ********************************************************************
% Game Over: Restore, Restart, or Quit?
%*******************************************************
\end{document}
% ********************************************************************
```

Bibliography file:

```
@inproceedings{Besancon:2016:UCMTT,
    Address = {Denver, United States},
    Author = {Besan{\c c}on, Lonni and Issartel, Paul and Ammi, Mehdi and Isenberg, Tobias},
    Booktitle = {{Proceedings of the ACM Conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems (CHI)}},
    Date-Added = {2017-09-12 07:38:33 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-09-12 07:38:33 +0000},
    Doi = {10.1145/3025453.3025863},
    Hal_Id = {hal-01436206},
    Hal_Version = {v1},
    Keywords = {usability study ; TUI ; tangible interaction ; ACM Classification Keywords H52 User Interfaces: Input devices and strategies Author Keywords 3D interaction ; mouse ; tactile interaction},
    Month = May,
    Pages = {4727--4740},
    Pdf = {https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01436206/file/chi2017.pdf},
    Title = {{Mouse, Tactile, and Tangible Input for 3D Manipulation}},
    Url = {https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01436206},
    Year = {2017},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01436206},
    Bdsk-Url-2 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/3025453.3025863}}
```

Comment: With current versions of `biblatex` there should be no superfluous comma in `\textcite`/`\citet`. There was a bug a while ago that caused the unwanted comma to appear, but that was fixed at least a year ago. What version do you use? Can you update `biblatex` and Biber?

Comment: @moewe thanks! I am using texmaker, so I don't know how to check for versions in there or even how to update... Investigating this now!

Comment: See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/373, https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/432, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312539/35864. Versions 3.3 and 3.4 are affected by two different problems in connection with commas appearing incorrectly in `\textcite`. From version 3.5 onwards, those bugs should be fixed. The current version is 3.7.

Comment: TeXmaker is an editor it is not your TeX system. There are two big TeX distributions MikTeX (for Windows, experimental Linux support was introduced very recently) and TeX live (cross-platform, on Mac OS also via MacTeX). You needs to find out which of the systems you use and read https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864

Comment: Your reference will be fully `authoryear` if you use `\usepackage[maxcitenames=2, style=authoryear, natbib=true, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` (so `style=authoryear` instead of only `citestyle=authoryear`). Ideally you would also look into using Biber instead of BibTeX (`backend=biber` and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864))

Comment: If you use MacTeX please read the TeX live answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55459/35864 nonetheless. It contains important explanations about the version scheme that the MacTeX gui answer does not into.

Comment: See also [biblatex, natbib=true compatibility with MikTeX 2.9](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/305783/35864)

Comment: @moewe too bad I did not see that link before. I have removed my old installation (2015) to install the new one and now I am facing File: blx-compat.def 2016/12/05 v3.7 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
)
! Package etoolbox Error: Toggle 'blx@bibtex8' already defined.

Comment: Mhhh, did you make sure that no traces of the old installation are left? Can you show the complete `.log` file of a minimal example that shows the error (see [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864))?

Comment: @moewe I don't have a MWE right now. The template is quite complicated and specific. But perhaps I just have an old aux file somewhere. Lemme try to remove all aux files

Comment: Do that first. But if you still get the error try to build an MWE from scratch.

Comment: @moewe done in the edit :). Thanks for the help BTW

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66213/discussion-between-moewe-and-lbes).